# ¿Como filtrar en un serializer?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, serialización

Hola buenos días quiero obtener en un webservice/Api todos los avalúos dependiendo de la agencia les dejo como lo tengo hasta ahora

Estos son mis modelos

```
class Agencia(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=50)
rfc = models.CharField(max_length=15)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
logo= models.ImageField(upload_to='logo/images/')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Usuarios(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
Agencia = models.ForeignKey('Agencia',null=True,blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Agencia

class Avaluo(models.Model):
coche = models.OneToOneField(Autoss,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
lugar = models.CharField(max_length=40)
fecha_visita = models.DateTimeField()
valuador = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios,blank=True,null=True)
Estatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.lugar
```

Serializer:

```
class usuarioAgencia(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Usuarios
    fields = '__all__'
```

Viewset:

```
class UsuarioAgenciaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = usuarioAgencia
queryset = Usuarios.objects.all()
```

Lo que quiero es Que al desplegar los resultados me los filtre por las agencias no se que me recomienden hacer

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estás usando [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), podrías añadir los filtros en el queryset de tu `ModelViewSet`. Algo parecido a esto:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset
      agencia_id = self.request.query_params.get('agencia', None)
      if agencia_id is not None:
          agencia_instance = get_object_or_404(Agencia, id=agencia_id)
          queryset = queryset.filter(agencia=agencia_instance)
      return queryset
```

Quedando tu Viewset tal que:

```
class UsuarioAgenciaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = usuarioAgencia
    queryset = Usuarios.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
          agencia_id = self.request.query_params.get('agencia', None)
          if agencia_id is not None:
              agencia_instance = get_object_or_404(Agencia, id=agencia_id)
              queryset = queryset.filter(agencia=agencia_instance)
          return queryset
```

En la documentación oficial [puedes encontrar muchos más ejemplos](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) de como filtrar en Views.

Por último, puedes utilizar [esta extensión de Django Rest Framework](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters) para poder usar filtros con parámetros como si fuese un listado de Django Admin

**Importante:** En este ejemplo he usado `djangorestframework==3.3.3`. Puede que en versiones anteriores sea un poco diferente.